A sequence of bounded functions
My question is related to the proof demonstrated in another question, posted in the following link:
Show that any uniformly convergent sequence of bounded functions is uniformly bounded
I tried to prove the theorem: let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions, that are uniformly converging to a limit function $f$ on an interval $I$. If every $f_n$ is bounded on the interval $I$, then $f$ is bounded as well.
I tried to show that either there is an upper bound on the set $\{f_n(x) | n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in I \}$, or we can construct a sequence $(M_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, of the bounds of $f_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that this sequence will either converge to a finite limit (the supremum of $f$ on $I$?), or will at least be bounded.
My questions are:

Does a constant which uniformly bounds all of the $f_n$'s exist? Meaning, is there a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and for all $x \in I$, $|f_n(x)|<c$?

Can we construct such a sequence $(M_n)$?


Intuitively, I think so because of the uniform convergence, but I had trouble showing it formally.
